# I'm trying to get my code to create a student database and no matter what I try it errors

Tags: c, database, file, switch-statement

It uses a switch statement to be able to look for different answers. As stated before it's a student record system and it can add students, show the full list and individually search for students.

The error looks to be a type error which makes sense due to the fact that I'm new to c.
Please let me know what to fix.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void addstu();
void studentrec();
void searchstu();
void del();

struct Student {
int ID;
char name[50];
char Class[20];
float gpa;
} student;

void main()
{
int num;
while(num!=4){
printf("\nWelcome to the student database menu, what would you like to do?")
printf("\n1. Add a student.\n 2. Search for a student(ID num req.) \n 3. Change student name. \n 4. Exit \nPlease enter the number you want for your request!");
scanf("d%",&num); 
switch(num){
case 1:
    addstu();
    break;
case 2:
    
    studentrec();
    char cont[100];
    printf("\n press any key to continue...");
    scanf("%c", &cont);
    if(cont!= ""){
    break;
    }
case 3:
    searchstu();
    printf("\n press any key to continue...");
    scanf("%c", &cont);
    if(cont!= ""){
    break;
    }
default:
     clrscr();
         getch();
         printf("\nEnter a valid number\n\n");
         printf("\nPress any key to continue.......");
         getch();
         clrscr();
         break;

void addstu(){
   
     char another;
     FILE *fp;
     int n,i;
     struct student info;
   do{
       clrscr();
       printf("\t\t\t\t=======Add Students Info=======\n\n\n"); 
       fp=fopen("information.txt","a"); //use can give any file name. Give the name with extention or without extention.
         
        printf("\n\t\t\tEnter Name     : ");
          scanf("%s",&info.name);
          printf("\n\t\t\tEnter Class(course) : ");
          scanf("%s",&info.Class);
          printf("\n\t\t\tEnter ID: ");
          scanf("%s",&info.ID);
          printf("\n\t\t\tEnter percentage: ");
          scanf("%f",&info.gpa);
       
      if(fp==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"can't open file");
    }else{
        printf("\nRecord stored successfuly\n");
    }
    
    fwrite(&info, sizeof(struct student), 1, fp); 
    fclose(fp);
    
    printf("\nYou want to add another record?(y/n) : ");
    
    
    scanf("%s",&another);
    
    
   }while(another=='y'||another=='Y');
}

void studentrecord(){
   
     FILE *fp;

    struct student info;
    fp=fopen("information.txt","r");
    
     printf("\n\n\n=======STUDENTS RECORD=======\n\n\n");
      
    if(fp==NULL){
        
        fprintf(stderr,"can't open file\n");
        exit(0);
    }else{
        printf("\nRECORDS :\n");
        
    }
        
        while(fread(&info,sizeof(struct student),1,fp)){
        printf("\nStudent Name  : %s",info.name);
        printf("\n Class         : %s",info.Class);
        printf("\n Percentage    : %f%",info.gpa);
        printf("\n ID           : %d",info.ID);
         }
        fclose(fp);
        getch();
    }
void searchstudent(){
       struct student info;
      FILE *fp; 
      int roll_no,found=0;
     
    fp=fopen("information.txt","r");
    printf("\n\n\n=======SEARCH STUDENTS RECORD=======\n\n\n");
    printf("\n\n\nEnter the roll no : ");
   
    scanf("%d",&roll_no);
     
    
    
    while(fread(&info,sizeof(struct student),1,fp)>0){
         
        if(info.roll_no==roll_no){
           
        found=1;
        printf("\nStudent Name  : %s",info.name);
        printf("\n Class         : %s",info.Class);
        printf("\n Percentage    : %f%",info.gpa);
        printf("\n ID           : %d",info.ID);
  
         }
       
    }
     
    if(!found){
       printf("\nRecord not found\n");
    }
  
    fclose(fp);
    getch();
    
}    
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Hint: `d%` and `%d` are two quite different things to `scanf`. Remember to **check your return values**. It's likely `scanf` is freaking out here but you're not listening.

Comment: You are missing some `}` in `main`. The end result is that your functions are _nested_ scope within `main`. This is _not_ standard C.

Comment: There are a lot of issues.  You are mixing up the  type `struct Student` and global variable `student`.  You should check return value of all i/o operations in particular `fopen()`.  The prototype for main should be `int main(void)` (`void main()` is a microsoft specific thing).  As is `conio.h`.  `num` is not initialized.  `d%` instead of `%d`.

Comment: `info.roll_no` refers to a non-existing member of `struct student`.

Comment: In the switch you use declare `char cont[100]` but then do &cont to read one character.  The conditional `break` is misplaced, you either need to use `goto` or a variable to break from switch statement within a loop.

Comment: As you are on windows and you save binary data you need the "b" mode for your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of issue with your program.  First we need to get it to compile:

1. Ensure `main()` is terminated with a `}` as you cannot declare functions within functions in standard C.
2. You refer to `struct Student` but you called the type `struct Student` and the global variable `student`.  Rename the struct to `struct student` and eliminate the global variable.
3. `searchstudent()` refers to a non-existing member `info.roll_no` of (now) `struct student`.  From the prompt in `main()`, it appears you want to search by `ID`.
4. The name of the function definitions don't match their use.  Simplified it just verbs but a good naming standard is a name space prefix like `student_` so `student_add()`, `student_list()` etc.

Now that the program compiles, we can fix a number of issues:

5. Incorrect format strings (`%c` when you pass in a string, `d%` when it should be `%d`, "%s" but using `&variable` which is already a pointer).
6. Conditional break in the switch statements.  Not sure what it's supposed to do so just removed a bunch of the prompt noise.
7. On Windows, you need to `fopen()` with the "b" mode for binary files.
8. Always specify a maximum field width when reading strings with `scanf()`.
9. `main()`: `num` is not initialized on first use.
10. `struct student`: `gpa` is not a percentage at least in the US.  You may want to validate the date.  If it's a percentage do you want to allow `>100`?.
11. (Partially fixed) You should check the return value of all I/O operations like `fopen()` and `scanf()`.
12. Used an `enum menu` to make the switch statement more readable.
13. I don't use Windows so I removed the non-portable bits like `#include <conio.h>` and `clrscr()` and `getch()`.  Feel free to add them back in.
14. (Not fixed) You can add multiple students with the same ID.  You probably want to prevent that.  Currently, search assumes unique IDs.
15. (Not fixed) Consider separating file i/o from the rest of your program for example my keeping the students in an in-memory array.  Read in the array on start-up and write it on exit (or even better write a new file and rename to new file to the old file).
16. (Partially fixed) When you look at the sample session it's very noisy due to prompt.  Consider only writing the menu prompt once on start-up, and maybe support a "?" or "h" to display it again.  The use of clearing the screen is a good hint that it's too verbose.
17. Eliminate magic values like the length of strings, or the path name of the file in favor of symbolic constants.
18. Spelling mistake (successfuly)
19. Extracted the print functionality to it's own function so it can be used in both `list()` and `search()`.
20. (Not fixed) Consider separating UI from the application logic.  Can you move all the prompts into `main()` and just pass the data each function need?  Take `add()` you have a prompt to add another student, but you might as well just have user type `1` to instead.  Then read the info and pass as arguments.
21. Menu didn't match behavior ("3. Change student name.") but 3 is `search()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CLASS_LEN 19
#define NAME_LEN 49
#define PATH "information.txt"
#define str(s) str2(s)
#define str2(s) #s

enum menu {
    ADD = 1,
    LIST,
    SEARCH,
    EXIT
};

struct student {
    int ID;
    char name[NAME_LEN + 1];
    char Class[CLASS_LEN + 1];
    float gpa;
};

void print(struct student *s);

void add() {
    FILE *fp=fopen(PATH, "ab");
    if(!fp){
        fprintf(stderr, "can't open file");
        return;
    }
    printf("=======Add Students Info=======\n\n");
    char another;
    do {
        struct student info;
        printf("Enter Name: ");
        scanf("%" str(NAME_LEN) "s", info.name);
        printf("Enter Class(course): ");
        scanf("%" str(CLASS_LEN) "s", info.Class);
        printf("Enter ID: ");
        scanf("%d",&info.ID);
        printf("Enter percentage: ");
        scanf("%f",&info.gpa);
        fwrite(&info, sizeof(struct student), 1, fp);
        printf("Record stored successfully\n");

        printf("\nYou want to add another record?(y/n) : ");
        scanf(" %c",&another);
    } while(another=='y'||another=='Y');
    fclose(fp);
}

void flush() {
    for(;;) {
        int c = getchar();
        if(c == '\n' || c == EOF)
            return;
    }
}

void list() {
    FILE *fp=fopen(PATH, "rb");
    if(!fp){
        fprintf(stderr,"can't open file\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("=======STUDENTS RECORD=======\n\n");
    struct student info;
    while(fread(&info,sizeof(struct student), 1, fp))
        print(&info);
    fclose(fp);
}

void print(struct student *s) {
    printf(
        "Student Name: %s\n"
        "Class: %s\n"
        "ID: %d\n"
        "Percentage: %f%\n"
        "\n",
        s->name,
        s->Class,
        s->ID,
        s->gpa
    );
}

void search() {
    FILE *fp=fopen(PATH, "rb");
    if(!fp) {
        printf("file could not be opened\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("=======SEARCH STUDENTS RECORD=======\n\n");
    struct student info;
    printf("Enter the student id: ");
    int ID;
    scanf("%d",&ID);
    printf("\n");
    while(fread(&info,sizeof(struct student),1,fp)>0){
        if(info.ID == ID) {
            print(&info);
            goto out;
        }
    }
    printf("Record not found\n\n");
out:
    fclose(fp);
}

int main(void) {
    enum menu num;
    do {
        printf(
            "Welcome to the student database menu, what would you like to do?\n"
            "1. Add a student\n"
            "2. List students\n"
            "3. Search for a student (ID num req)\n"
            "4. Exit\n"
            "Please enter the number you want for your request! "
        );
        if(scanf("%d", &num) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "scanf failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("\n");
        switch(num) {
            case ADD:
                add();
                break;
            case LIST:
                list();
                break;
            case SEARCH:
                search();
                break;
            case EXIT:
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid input\n\n");
                flush();
                break;
        }
    } while(num!=4);
}
```

and example session (with minor edits; added a newline I think instead of fixing the code and redoing it):

```
Welcome to the student database menu, what would you like to do?
1. Add a student
2. List students
3. Search for a student (ID num req)
4. Exit
Please enter the number you want for your request! 1

=======Add Students Info=======

Enter Name: john
Enter Class(course): finance 
Enter ID: 1
Enter percentage: 52
Record stored successfully

You want to add another record?(y/n) : n

Welcome to the student database menu, what would you like to do?
1. Add a student
2. List students
3. Search for a student (ID num req)
4. Exit
Please enter the number you want for your request! 2

=======STUDENTS RECORD=======

Student Name: john
Class: finance
ID: 1
Percentage: 52.000000

Welcome to the student database menu, what would you like to do?
1. Add a student
2. List students
3. Search for a student (ID num req)
4. Exit
Please enter the number you want for your request! 3

=======SEARCH STUDENTS RECORD=======

Enter the student id: 1

Student Name: john
Class: finance
ID: 1
Percentage: 52.000000

Welcome to the student database menu, what would you like to do?
1. Add a student
2. List students
3. Search for a student (ID num req)
4. Exit
Please enter the number you want for your request! 4
```